# Java wait() not Throwing InterruptedException

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, wait, notify

I have an object on **thread A** that is calling `wait()` while another object on **thread B** does some work then calls **thread A**'s object's `notify()`. Thread A then performs some post-processing.

My problem is pretty straightforward:

```
synchronized(this)
{
    while(!flag)
    {
        try
        {
            wait();
            getLogger().info("No longer waiting");
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie)
        {
            getLogger().info("Wait threw InterruptedException");
        }
    }
}
```

Results in an info message of "No longer waiting" instead of "Wait threw InterruptedException".

I am confused, because of this ([http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29)):

> **Throws:**
>
> **InterruptedException** - if another thread interrupted the
>   current thread before or while the current thread was waiting for a
>   notification. The interrupted status of the current thread is cleared
>   when this exception is thrown.

Why am I getting odd behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: Another thread calling `notify` on your object does not qualify as an interruption.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When a thread waits using `wait()`, he actually waits for `notify()`. So once `notify()` has been called by the other thread, this thread will continue, if you will call `interrupt()`, you would get the exception.

Also, from the documents you linked to:

> Causes current thread to wait until
>   another thread invokes the notify()
>   method or the notifyAll() method for
>   this object

`notify` releases the thread from the lock.

> InterruptedException - if another
>   thread interrupted the current thread
>   before or while the current thread was
>   waiting for a notification.

Comment: Thanks, I was assuming that notify() caused wait() to throw an InterruptedException.

Answer (score 3):

`notify()` does not make `wait()` throw `InterruptedException`. `notify()` let `wait()` continue the normal program flow.

Answer (score 2):

`notify()` is not an abnormal termintation for a thread that is `wait()`-ing.  You'd get the exception if, for instance, the thread was terminated before `notify()` was called - not as a result of `notify()` being called. The thread hasn't been interrupted - it's been awoken.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have a bug in that code. Wait should always be invoked in a loop, and check a condition after waking up.

wait can be awaken by a spurious wakeup. See the javadoc [wait()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29)

Comment: Given that we haven't seen any of the context of the code, you can't tell that it's got a bug. It's not in a synchronized block either, but I'm assuming there's one somewhere.

Comment: @Jon Skeet. The original post didn't have a loop with a condition, and the OP said "Thread A then performs some post-processing." The means that he wanted to wait till the other thread had completed processing. A wait without a condition to check is then a bug, due to spurious wakeups. The thread can be awaken without a notify and would then start post processing before the other thread had completed.